# Use gulp-useref how to add extra files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, gulp-useref

I html file like this:

```
...
<!-- build:js build/js/vendor.js -->
<script src="dep/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Build file like this:

```
<script src="build/js/vendor.xxxxxxxx.js"></script>
```

Now I use `gulp-angular-templatecache` package all the view files, generate a template.js, I would like to add this document to the compiled html file inside, how to do it?

I found the `gulp-useref` document in the `additionalStreams` settings options, but I used to find what is not want to achieve the function.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in another way.

Write on the page first:

```
<!-- build:templates --><!-- endbuild -->
```

Before packing with `gulp-replace` replaced with like this:

```
<!-- build:js build/js/templates.js -->
    <script src="build/js/templates.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Finally unify compilation.

Code:

```
var indexHtmlFilter = $.filter(['**/*', '!**/index_dev.html'], {
    restore: true
});

var fontglyphiconsMatch = /^\.\.\/fonts\/glyphicons/;
var fontawesomeMatch = /^\.\.\/fonts\/fontawesome-/;
var imgMatch = /^\.\.\/img\//;

var matchUrlType = function(url){
    if(fontglyphiconsMatch.test(url))
        return  url.replace(/^\.\./, '/dep/bootstrap-css-only');

    if(fontawesomeMatch.test(url))
        return url.replace(/^\.\./, '/dep/font-awesome');

    if(imgMatch.test(url))
        return url.replace(/^\.\./, '');
};
gulp.src('app/index_dev.html')
    .pipe($.htmlReplace({
        templates: `
            <!-- build:js build/js/templates.js -->
            <script src="build/js/templates.js"></script>
            <!-- endbuild -->
            `
    }))
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify({
        output: {
            ascii_only: true
        }
    })))
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.modifyCssUrls({
        modify: matchUrlType
    })))
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.cleanCss()))
    .pipe(indexHtmlFilter)
    .pipe($.rev())
    .pipe($.revFormat({
        prefix: '.'
    }))
    .pipe(indexHtmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.htmlmin({
        collapseWhitespace: true
    })))
    .pipe($.if('index_dev.html', $.rename('index.html')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'));
```